# Запретить интерпретацию .htaccess внутри одного каталога

Tags: php, .htaccess

Надо  настроить **.htaccess** таким образом, чтобы он действовал, или все настройки которые в нем есть, работати для всего сайта, кроме одного каталога, или запретить **.htaccess**  в одном каталоге.

Скажем так: все, что для клиента прописано в **.htaccess**, блокирует то, что надо для админки.

P.S. Мне не надо запретить доступ до каталога или что-то в этом роде, а исключить папку из действия вышележащих **.htaccess**.

**Обновление**

```
RewriteRule .* — [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
RewriteRule .* — [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]
```

Надо чтобы в админке кеширование не работало.

**Обновление**

Попробовал дописать Rewrite. Верно?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/admin/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* — [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
RewriteRule .* — [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]
```

Comment: Исключить папку от действия вышележащего .htaccess невозможно. Надо либо в том .htaccess правила висать так что бы они распространялись только на определенные папки. Либо в требуемой папке класть .htaccess отменяющий правила заданные в верхнем (ну или меняющий на противоположные, как получится)

Comment: Ну и дописать ему RewriteCond для исключения каталога

Comment: Вряд ли HTTP_HOST - потому как это только имя хоста, а вам надо REQUEST_URI

Comment: Не работает такой вариант, тупо грузиться вечность

Comment: Не думаю что REQUEST_URI начинается на admin, возможно там весь запрос целиком я не особо силен в rewrite. В общем `^` попробуйте убрать, оно конечно должно будет на все папки admin срабатывать, но не думаю что их много

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

предуведомление: работоспособность решения не проверял. опираюсь на упоминание, например, [по этой ссылке](https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3428087.htm).

---

для того, чтобы запретить (в данном каталоге и глубже) интерпретацию `.htaccess` (находящегося в данном каталоге) и действие файлов `.htaccess` из вышележащих каталогов, можно воспользоваться директивой [`allowoverride none`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) внутри секции [`directory`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) в соответствующей секции [`virtualhost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) конфигурации *apache*.

---

пример.

docroot сайта: `/var/www/site`
нужный каталог: `/var/www/site/kata/log`

тогда конфигурация будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<virtualhost ...>
  ...
  documentroot /var/www/site
  ...
  <directory /var/www/site/kata/log>
    allowoverride none
    ...
  </directory>
  ...
</virtualhost>
```